# Gnuplot heatmap from 3D data

Tags: dictionary, 3d, gnuplot, heatmap, heat

I have a data file prepared in three columns: 'inclination' 'azimuth' 'separation'. Inclination and azimuth correspond to the angular position of points in my point cloud and separation is a value associated with each one of those points (which denotes how far each point is from its nearest neighbour in a reference point cloud that it's being compared to.

I want to create a 2D plot of inclination vs azimuth and for each position use the separation value to make a 'heatmap' or colour scale. Ideally the results will be interpolated to fill the entire plot with data.

As you'll see from my code I'm new to gnuplot and will appreciate as much hand holding as you're willing to give.

```
set xlabel 'inclination'
set ylabel 'azimuth'
set view map
set palette rgbformulae 10,13,33
set cbrange[0:100]
set xrange [0:180]
set yrange [-180:180]
set term png size 840,840
set output 'testplot.png'

set pm3d map
set dgrid3d

splot 'testdegscaled.txt' using 1:2:3 w pm3d
```

Sample of my data is here: http://pastebin.com/xc1x5j64

Current output:

[image]

Any advice is appreciated!

Output from `show version long`: G N U P L O T
        Version 5.0 patchlevel 2    last modified 2015-12-24

```
    Copyright (C) 1986-1993, 1998, 2004, 2007-2015
    Thomas Williams, Colin Kelley and many others

    gnuplot home:     http://www.gnuplot.info
    faq, bugs, etc:   type "help FAQ"
    immediate help:   type "help"  (plot window: hit 'h')
    Compile options:
    -READLINE  +LIBREADLINE  +HISTORY  
    -BACKWARDS_COMPATIBILITY  +BINARY_DATA  
    +GD_PNG  +GD_JPEG  +GD_TTF  +GD_GIF  +ANIMATION  
    -USE_CWDRC  +X11  +X11_POLYGON  +MULTIBYTE  +X11_EXTERNAL +USE_MOUSE          +HIDDEN3D_QUADTREE  
    +DATASTRINGS  +HISTOGRAMS  +OBJECTS  +STRINGVARS  +MACROS  +THIN_SPLINES  +IMAGE                  +USER_LINETYPES +STATS +EXTERNAL_FUNCTIONS 
    MAX_PARALLEL_AXES=7

    GNUPLOT_DRIVER_DIR = "/usr/local/Cellar/gnuplot/5.0.2/libexec/gnuplot/5.0"
    GNUPLOT_PS_DIR     = "/usr/local/Cellar/gnuplot/5.0.2/share/gnuplot/5.0/PostScript"
    HELPFILE           = "/usr/local/Cellar/gnuplot/5.0.2/share/gnuplot/5.0/gnuplot.gih"
```

Comment: It works for me: http://i.imgur.com/BsmDMUc.png What version of gnuplot are you? can you update the question by providing the output of `show version long` ?

Comment: @bibi Thanks for your reply, I've updated the question with the output you requested

Comment: @bibi Okay, so I've just tested the sample I uploaded and get the same result. Rookie mistake, I should have done that in the first place. When I try to incorporate the entire data set, that's when I get the output in the question.

Could reprojection cause the problem I'm encountering? By reprojection I mean - because of the irregular shape of my point cloud there may be several instances of two more separation values for for the same angular position.

Comment: try to plot `with lines` to check if the mesh is right

Comment: Can you try to upload somewhere the real data?

Comment: @bibi unfortunately the data that I'm trying to plot is part of a thesis research project and I can't publish anything before final submission. A colleague is going to show me how he makes heatmaps from 3D data using matlab and I'll probably use his method, thanks for your help though.